# Clojure call series of functions and store their return values

Tags: clojure, datomic

I'm building a datomic schema and have the following at the foot of my `clj` file which defines and transacts schema and initial data.  The functions being called below each call `d/transact`.

```clj
(defn recreate-database []
  "To recreate db after running delete-database in bin/repl"
  (pt1-transact-schema)
  (pt1-transact-data)
  (pt2-transact-schema)
  (pt2-transact-data)
  (pt3-transact-schema)
  (pt3-transact-data))
```

By default we only see the return value of the last form, but I'd like to see, or save, the result of each of the six function calls.

Wondering what a nice way to do this is.

Thought of something like `(map (comp println eval) [functions])`, but that's not right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is also a nice functional composition function called `juxt`:

```
user> ((juxt + - * /) 1 2)
;;=> [3 -1 2 1/2]

user> ((juxt (constantly 1) (constantly 2) (constantly 3)))
;;=> [1 2 3]
```

or in your case:

```
(def recreate-database (juxt pt1-transact-schema
                             pt1-transact-data
                             pt2-transact-schema
                             pt2-transact-data
                             pt3-transact-schema
                             pt3-transact-data))
```

Comment: the most elegant solution. i note `juxt` is higher order function, the `def` above (note it's not a `defn`) returns a function (because that's what `juxt` does), which must then be called, like `(recreate-database)`. beautiful...

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
(defn recreate-database []
  "To recreate db after running delete-database in bin/repl"

  (mapv #(%) [pt1-transact-schema
              pt1-transact-data
              pt2-transact-schema
              pt2-transact-data
              pt3-transact-schema
              pt3-transact-data]))
```

The expression `#(%)` is a shorthand notation for a lambda function that takes one argument, representing a function, and calls that function. If you find it more readable, you can replace that expression by `(fn [f] (f))`.

Answer (score 1):

With datomic, all you need is a connection and a list of tx-data.  Then you can use `map` to return the transact result on each step (i.e. each tx-data):

```clj
(defn recreate-database [conn & tx-data]
  (->> tx-data
       (map (partial d/transact conn))
       doall))
```

Comment: That's very cool. I need it to not insert everything in one transaction, as I'm currently relying on `txInstant` rather than a reified domain time for some of my data (may change this), and need different tx times to test the domain logic, but I see that this tiny fn will transact each map it's given separately. (the `tx-data` it takes actually being a list of the `:tx-data` maps datomic expects). Superb solution!