# Clojure function to realise a sequence

Tags: clojure, datomic

I have the following function to collect datomic transaction reports, output of this [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61636534/clojure-call-series-of-functions-and-store-their-return-values/61640221#61640221).

```clj
(def recreate-database
  "Defines a function which when called will call each of the four given
   functions and return a collection containing the output of each."
  (juxt pt1-transact-schema
        pt1-transact-data
        pt2-transact-schema
        pt2-transact-data))
```

The next step is that each of these functions may itself call not one but a series of transactions, so the complete result desired will be a nested collection of transaction reports for the initial database build.

I had the following, which was unsuitable, because when called from `recreate-database` above, only the last transaction report comes through, a function of course only returning its final form.

```clj
(defn pt1-transact-data []
  (d/transact conn {:tx-data pt1-user-data})
  (d/transact conn {:tx-data pt1-path-data})
  (d/transact conn {:tx-data pt1-series-data}))
```

So I arrived at the following

```clj
(defn pt1-transact-data []
  (map identity
    [(d/transact conn {:tx-data pt1-user-data})
     (d/transact conn {:tx-data pt1-path-data})
     (d/transact conn {:tx-data pt1-series-data})
     (d/transact conn {:tx-data pt1-path-series-data})]))
```

This works fine, except there's still incidental complexity. `map identity` is linguistically low level in relation to intended meaning here.

Hence thinking was, we just need to "*realize the sequence*", so I extracted:

```clj
(defn realize-all [coll] (map identity coll))
```

Then I remembered `doall`. 
Just using that works here too.

So, is this the same as what `doall` does?

I note from `(source doall)` it doesn't appear the same, that leads to `dorun`, which leads to... `recur`.

So `map identity` or `doall` or `dorun` appear to serve similar purpose here.

Are these equivalent? Is there more to say?

Comment: `map identity` produces another lazy sequence that needs to be realised before anything happens. I'm guessing you're calling it at a repl which is making you think it's the thing realizing it (when the repl tries to print the result, it gets realised). `dorun` and `doall` are equivalent except `doall` retains the head of the seq and returns it. if it's your intention not to do anything with the returned seq, then use `dorun`. It will use less memory and states your intent more clearly.

Comment: you could also use `mapv`, which is an eager version of map

Comment: @mwal Note that this question essentially has nothing to do with Datomic and everything to do with Clojure, so you might want to remove the Datomic tag.

I would also rework the title, e.g to "how ot return several successive results in a collection in Clojure".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you just wrap it in a vector? that seems to be the easiest solution:

```
(defn pt1-transact-data []
  [(d/transact conn {:tx-data pt1-user-data})
   (d/transact conn {:tx-data pt1-path-data})
   (d/transact conn {:tx-data pt1-series-data})])
```

or else you could use `mapv`:

```
(defn pt1-transact-data []
  (mapv (partial d/transact conn)
        [{:tx-data pt1-user-data}
         {:tx-data pt1-path-data}
         {:tx-data pt1-series-data}))
```

Comment: "just wrap it in a vector" :)  absolutely. my homework now is why i didn't see that. i think it's time to do SICP... :)